# Python telegram bot : InlineKeyboardButton that call a function

Tags: python, telegram, telegram-bot, python-telegram-bot

I'm creating a telegram bot with the python-telegram-bot library and I would like to put buttons that execute a command but it doesn't work.

```
def start(update: Update, context: CallbackContext) -> None:
    keyboard = [[InlineKeyboardButton('Help', callback_data='help')],
              [InlineKeyboardButton('Start', callback_data='start')]]
    menu_choices = InlineKeyboardMarkup(keyboard)
    update.message.reply_text("start with commands", reply_markup=menu_choices)

def button(update: Update, context: CallbackContext) -> None:
    query = update.callback_query

    query.answer()
    
    choice = query.data
    
    if choice == 'help':
        help(update, context)
    if choice == 'start':
        start(update, context)
    else:
        print("error")

    query.edit_message_text(text=f"Selected option: {query.data}")

def help(update: Update, context: CallbackContext) -> None:
    update.message.reply_text("Use /start to test this bot.")

def main():
    updater = Updater(TOKEN, use_context=True)

    # Get the dispatcher to register handlers
    dp = updater.dispatcher
    dp.add_handler(CallbackQueryHandler(button))

    allowed_updates = ["message", "callback_query"]

    # Start the Bot
    updater.start_webhook(listen="0.0.0.0",
                          port=int(PORT),
                          url_path=TOKEN,
                          allowed_updates=allowed_updates)

    updater.idle()
```

I have an error :

```
__main__ - WARNING - Update "{'update_id': XXXX, 'callback_query':...}" caused error "'property' object does not support item assignment"
```

Apparently you can't directly call the start and help functions in the button function.

Comment: Are you sure, that you set up list of "allowed_updates" to receive callbacks not just messages?

Comment: I don't think so. Do you have a link to an implementation of "allowed_updates"?

Comment: what line of code is that error message referencing to?

Comment: You're using an old error handler, which hides the traceback. Please set up logging (https://github.com/python-telegram-bot/python-telegram-bot#logging) and either remove your error handler or use this one: https://github.com/python-telegram-bot/python-telegram-bot/blob/master/examples/errorhandlerbot.py. Then update your question with the full traceback :)